# What is the best image size to use on mobile devices? (HTML)

Tags: image, mobile, device

I would be using Google for this, but it would display outdated info, and that's not what I want.

Basing from statistics of 2012,cellphones and tablets have shifted the way we interact with websites. Due to that, I'm planning going fully mobile and I would like to know which is the "standard" image size I should implement (for mobile display only) so they don't slow down cellular connections and the browsing session.  Of course... they shouldn't look crap either

Thanks  a lot!

Answer (score 0):

40 kb seems to be best images sizes all images used in your original website should be reduced from the original size to this size. as most mobile devices will not be compatible with any image size bigger than this.